Tangent line of integral
We know that if $F(x) = \int_2^x g(t)dt$, then the slope of the tangent line to $F$ at a point $x_0$ is $$F’(x_0) = g(x_0)$$ by fundamental theorem of calculus.
Now suppose that we want to find the slope of the tangent line at $x_0 =1$, ($1$ is outside the limits of integration), is correct to say that $$F’(1) = - g(1) $$ is the slope of the tangente line?
Thanks.
Edit: $g$ continous on all reals.

Not necessarily, $F'(1)$ could be undefined for all you know.

@BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I forgot to say that g was continous on all reals

In that case, yes.
